# sql server group by datetime cut-off point of 10:00am

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime, group-by

I'm trying to write a Microsoft SQL Server 2005 query that counts a total value, grouped by date with a cut-off point of 10:00am ?

eg: Table Orders

```
DateReceived              Total

01-01-2012 06:10:01       2       
01-01-2012 08:10:01       2   
01-01-2012 10:10:01       4   
02-01-2012 08:00:07       4   
02-01-2012 10:00:07       4
```

I'd like to count the daily total, using 10:00 am as the cut-off point, so any orders before 10:00am appear in the total for the day before, and after 10:00 am in the total for that day.

I'm hoping to see query results like:

```
DateReceived              Total

31-12-2011                4       
01-01-2012                8   
02-01-2012                4
```

I know how to group by just the date in Microsoft SQL Server:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(varchar, [DateReceived], 111) AS [dt_DateReceived], 
SUM([Total]) AS perday
FROM         [Orders] 
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar, [DateReceived], 111)
ORDER BY [DateReceived] DESC
```

However I am unsure how to add a cut off time of 10:00am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Using MySQL, I can achieve this by grouping on a subtracted interval, however am unsure how to translate this to SQL Server:

```
GROUP BY
  DATE(DATE_SUB( DateReceived , INTERVAL 10 HOUR))
```

Could anyone advise?

Thank you,
Jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the translation:

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(hour, -10, [DateReceived]), 111) AS [dt_DateReceived], 
  SUM([Total]) AS perday
FROM [Orders] 
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(hour, -10, [DateReceived]), 111)
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

**Test script**

*Note that my local datetime format is yyyy-mm-dd*

```
;WITH Orders AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        (CAST('2012-01-01 06:10:01' AS DATETIME), 2)
        , ('2012-01-01 08:10:01', 2)
        , ('2012-01-01 10:10:01', 4)
        , ('2012-01-02 08:00:07', 4)
        , ('2012-01-02 10:00:07', 4)
    ) AS Orders (DateReceived, Total)       
)
SELECT  CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(hour, -10, [DateReceived]), 111) AS [dt_DateReceived]
        , SUM([Total]) AS perday
FROM    [Orders] 
GROUP BY 
        CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(hour, -10, [DateReceived]), 111)
ORDER BY 
        1
```

The testscript can be executed [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/60123/group-by-datetime-cut-off-point)

PS: Distinction is not needed

Comment: + I didn't quite understand the question until I ran your solution <vbg>.

Comment: Hi Oleg,  Apologies for the late reply, I had been pulled onto another project.  Thank you for the detailed answer and  test script - perfect!   Much appreciated.